# Understanding Explain Plan on Composite Index

Tags: postgresql

On PostgreSQL `12.1`, given:

```
postgres=> create table abc(a int not null, b text not null, c boolean not null);
CREATE TABLE

postgres=> create index on abc (a, b, c);
CREATE INDEX
```

I then prepared a query that only filters on `a`, i.e. the first element in the index.

```
postgres=> prepare only_a(int) as select 42 from abc where a = 1;
PREPARE

postgres=> explain execute only_a(100);
                                 QUERY PLAN                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on abc  (cost=4.20..13.67 rows=6 width=4)
   Recheck Cond: (a = 1)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on abc_a_b_c_idx  (cost=0.00..4.20 rows=6 width=0)
         Index Cond: (a = 1)
(4 rows)
```

It's able to use the index in order to filter on `a`, per the above.

Then, I prepared a query that filters on `a` and `c`, i.e. does not use `b`.

```
postgres=> prepare a_and_c(int) as select 42 from abc where a = 1 and c = true;
PREPARE
```

Then, I ran `explain execute`,

```
postgres=> explain execute a_and_c(100);
                                 QUERY PLAN                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on abc  (cost=4.21..11.32 rows=3 width=4)
   Recheck Cond: (a = 1)
   Filter: c
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on abc_a_b_c_idx  (cost=0.00..4.21 rows=3 width=0)
         Index Cond: ((a = 1) AND (c = true))
(5 rows)
```

My understanding is that `Index Cond: ((a = 1) AND (c = true))` means that `abc_a_b_c_idx` was able to use both `a` and `c` values, despite `b` not being involved in the `where`.

If so, how can `c` be used since `b` is not used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"c" is just being used as an in-index filter.  It jumps to the part of the index where "a"=1 and scans it until "a" becomes >1.  For all of those rows it filters out anything where "c" is not true, based on the value of "c" found in the index.

It is unfortunate that the EXPLAIN syntax doesn't distinguish a column used for jumping to a specific part of the index (or stopping in index scan at the end of the relevant values), from one just used for filtering within the index.  But EXPLAIN doesn't understand the internals of indexes, it just knows that "c" is being used, it doesn't know how efficiently it is being used.

Answer (score 2):

You are right to wonder, and the reason is a sloppiness in PostgreSQL's explain output.

During an index scan, some of the conditions can be used to scan the index, and some conditions can be used as a filter, that is an additional condition imposed on the rows found during the index scan.

Now `a = 1` clearly is a condition that can be used for scanning the index.

The problem is that there are two ways to filter during an index scan:

1. discard index tuples while they are scanned, before the table is accessed.
2. discard result rows based on a condition on values fetched from the table during the index scan.

The second kind is displayed as `filter` in `EXPLAIN`, but the first kind of filter is shown as part of the scan condition. This is what your condition `c = true` is.

There is no way to tell a scan condition from a filter of the first kind in `EXPLAIN` output.

Note that the first kind of filter is more efficient, since it reduces the number of rows that have to be fetched from the heap, which is the expensive part of an index scan.